# os-prober finds nixos, but it doesn't appear in grub menu

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot, grub, nixos

If I run update-grub it sees all the OSes on my machine (Mint, Windows (work), Windows (games) and NixOs):

```
➜  ~ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50_linuxmint.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/Stylish/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-97-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-97-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-94-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-94-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-91-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdd1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found NixOS 23.11 (Tapir) (23.11) on /dev/sdd5
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

But when I restart, NixOs doesn't appear in the menu, and if I look at grub.cfg it only has mint and Windows in it.

```
…
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-f9edbfda-0552-4a82-a93c-60525d334646' {
    …
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-f9edbfda-0552-4a82-a93c-60525d334646' {
… 
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-C745-9EFB' {
    …
}
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdd1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-22F0-7DFB' {
    …
}
```

Comment: Are all installs UEFI on gpt partitioned drives? I prefer to turn off os-prober and add my own boot stanzas to 40_custom. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen Lots of discussion & examples. May be best to read first page & jump to last page & work backwards for newest examples.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit hazy about what the difference is between UEFI and GPT, I'll have a look at those links.

Comment: UEFI is boot mode as opposed to  old BIOS. Many systems still call it BIOS. My Dell with 11th Gen Intel calls it "BIOS" but once in BIOS it says it only supports UEFI boot. Partitioning is either gpt or very old MBR(msdos). Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot or MBR for BIOS boot. Linux will install in either mode to either partition scheme, but use UEFI with gpt or if drive is Linux only, you can use the better gpt with BIOS boot.